# Shorten Imports in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I decided to shorten my imports in my react app. So I configured the `jsconfig.json`.

My problem is that its giving error on importing.

```
Failed to compile. ./src/actions/appActions.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@constants'
```

Please see codes below.

**REPO**

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rp5AagwvMyBRbhb4svHUqyCYH3ROA-L3?usp=sharing
```

**jsconfig.json**

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["src/components"],
      "@actions": ["src/actions"],
      "@constants": ["src/constants"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
      "@services": ["src/services"],
      "@assets": ["src/assets"]
    }
  }
}
```

**appActions.js**

```
import { appConstants } from '@constants';

export const setAPIErrorMessage = (error) => {
  return {
    type: appConstants.SET_API_ERROR_MESSAGE,
    payload: error,
  };
};

export const setAPISuccessMessage = (error) => {
  return {
    type: appConstants.SET_API_SUCCESS_MESSAGE,
    payload: error,
  };
};
```

**constants > index.js**

```
export * from './authConstants';
export * from './appConstants';
```

**constants > appConstants.js**

```
export const appConstants = {
  SET_API_ERROR_MESSAGE: 'SET_API_ERROR_MESSAGE',
  SET_API_SUCCESS_MESSAGE: 'SET_API_SUCCESS_MESSAGE',
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You write `"@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],`, but import from `import appConstants from '@constants';`. For my understanding the matcher expects something after `@constants`...

Try using something like

```
import { appConstants } from '@constants/appConstants';
```

Or edit your jsconfig file to something like

```
"@constants": ["src/constants"],
```

Comment: Updated question both on `jsconfig.json` and `appActions.js` and still same error

Comment: have you tried `import {appConstants} from '@constants/appConstants';`? locally this works for me, while `"@constants": ["src/constants"],` doesn't work

Comment: here's my repo on gdrive

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rp5AagwvMyBRbhb4svHUqyCYH3ROA-L3?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you check my repo?

Answer (score 0):

Just update import like this:

```
import { appConstants } from '@constants';
```

And add a path in config `src/constants`:

```
"@constants": ["src/constants"],
"@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
```

Comment: Updated question both on `jsconfig.json` and `appActions.js` and still same error

Comment: Try the anwser.

Comment: Yes, I followed your answer. You may check my edited question

Comment: Add `"@constants": ["src/constants"],` without `/*`

Comment: here's my repo on gdrive

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rp5AagwvMyBRbhb4svHUqyCYH3ROA-L3?usp=sharing

Comment: You should restart your project

Comment: I did, you may check my repo

Comment: Have you check my repo?